# Is it wrong to say "owinings" as a synonym of "possessions"? If no, what is the difference?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-difference

I am wondering is it absolutely wrong to say something like this (self-made example):

> He laid against the tree and though of his beloved **ownings**- family, friends and country.

Is that wrong? I discovered that Wiktionary considers this as a correct plural noun, but I am not sure about it.

Is that correct? If so, what is the difference between "ownings" and "possessions"? I don't know why "owning" strikes me a more emotional term that "possessions" does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ownings** is not a standard English word.

If you want a synonym for **possessions** that is along the lines you are thinking, then you could use **belongings**.

In my mind, "possessions" has a slight tendency to refer to things you own that are comparatively valuable, while "belongings" may refer to one's personal effects, which are typically not worth much in terms of money but may have sentimental value.

A lot of times people will use the phrase them "personal belongings."  You can also say "personal possessions," though, too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's interesting to see that belongings is a legit plural.